# Geolocation API error while debugging angular app on mobile

Tags: angular, geolocation, angular-cli

I am creating an angular app that uses GeoLocation API to fetch user location. I use the function `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` to get the location of user. This works fine on PC and retrieves approximate latitude and longitude but while using the same function on mobile there is a Position Error with code `1` and message "Only secure origins are allowed (see: [this](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/prefer-secure-origins-for-powerful-new-features) link).". On PC the url I use to access the application is `localhost:4200` where as on mobile I use `192.168.xx.xxx:4200`. I am serving the app through angular-cli with command `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --open`

I tried visiting [this](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/prefer-secure-origins-for-powerful-new-features) website  as mentioned in error which states that:

> “Secure origins” are origins that match at least one of the following (scheme, host, port) patterns: 
>   (https, *, *)
>   (wss, *, *)
>   (*, localhost, *)
>   (*, 127/8, *)
>   (*, ::1/128, *)
>   (file, *, —)
>   (chrome-extension, *, —)

Now the error seems legitimate as the url on mobile doesn't seem to follow the patterns mentioned above and location API requires these origins for working.

But I am unable to figure out how to run the app on mobile from secure origin. Can you guide me in solving this problem so I can get user location while debugging App on mobile ?

Answer (score -1):

You could configure an IIS site to host it on your local machine, you can provide your own custom site name, then you can access this from your other devices if you are on the same network.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VkGmaVm6-IQ - Link to  a tutorial

Hope this helps